# How to make a span fully clickable?

Tags: jquery, anchor

I'd like to make a span fully clickable.

```
<span><a href="#" title="Remove" id="159" class="remove">159</a><input type="hidden" name="t[1][p][]" value="159"></span>
```

The span is assigned a background image which is floated to the right. The image is a plus sign which will basically serve to indicate the record can be moved to another div.

Rather than having a link and an image both clickable, is it possible to simply have the whole span act like a anchor?

The click must be detected by jQuery.

Comment: Why not give the background image to the `<a>`? The hidden input can be accounted for using `$('.remove').next()`.

Comment: Have you not got any jQuery code already?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the Anchor block level (ie display:block) and it will fill the span, assuming your span itself has a defined size (otherwise it will just wrap the anchor and they will both be the same size)

Answer (score 10):

HTML:

```
<span id="myspan">....</span>
```

Script:

```
$("#myspan").click(function(){
    alert('I got a click');
});
```

Comment: Hahaha. Simple and straightforward. I like it :)

Comment: within that function if you add after the first alert `$('a',this).click()` it will activate click the a link but then it would click the span again automatically, if you click the href directly it would click the span aswell..

Comment: This does not work in cases like the question. Rephrasing OP more simply:
`<span class="myspan">span span<i style="float:right;">spannidy span</i></span>` has an area in the middle that's not clickable.

Answer (score 3):

`$("a.remove").closest("span").click(function(){alert('Test');});` will do.

By the way, it's not a good idea to set the id to a numeric-only value. (You have the `id` of the `a` element set to "159"). This makes your markup invalid, as any identifier has to start with a latin character followed by characters, digits, dashes etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a.remove').closest('span').click(function(){
    $('a.remove', this).trigger('click');
})
```

This will fire the link's click event too.

Comment: I like this as it is narrowing down the spans to the ones containing the `remove` links. +1

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mDLwZ/1/

I think there's a problem with the fact that when you click the span, it clicks the href inside for some reason, here's a small work around.